# What's the purpose of the T568A/B's color wires?

Tags: network

I know that pair 3 in T568A is used for transmitting data while pair 2 is used for receiving data. In T568B the logic is reverse, meaning pair 2 is for Tx and pair 3 is for Rx.

What's the purpose of the blue and brown pairs?

[image]

Comment: They are used in 1000Base-T, e.g. as shown at [Ethernet 1000Base-T (Gigabit ethernet) pinout](https://pinoutguide.com/Net/ethernet1000baset_pinout.shtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10BaseT and 100BaseT Ethernet uses only 2 pairs (pins 1,2,3,6).

Standard telephone uses blue wiring (pins 4 and 5).

Gigabit Ethernet and HDBaseT uses all 4 pairs.

Some other configurations exist as well.